# Rails 5: Give full access to admin with devise gem installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have installed the `devise gem` and I have created three users: `admin, seller and viewer`. Each user has it's own `model, sessions-controllers, registrations-controllers and views`.

At this point I would like to give full access to the `admin` in order to view, add, edit or delete products that where created by the users, and basically give the admin full access to everything.

I'm familiar with gems such as `rails-admin`, `active-admin`, `cancan`, `rolify` & `pundit` but I was wondering if there is another way to implement this?

Comment: If you look for some other way, then you mostly should be NOT satisfied with all of this solutions. If you say what are your reasons for looking other alternatives, It will be easier for me to help you.

Comment: Also, such model split in 90% is very bad approach. It's good only if you really sure what are you doing, but I have strong doubts about that. Rails has 2 great patterns: STI/MTI (easy to google) for such situations. I would strongly recommend you to go with one of it

Comment: Thanks for the info @AntonTkachov.. I ended up using separate models for each user because this systems is more stable and works better when a lot of users are expected. I reached this conclusion after some extensive research I've done. I might be wrong though, since i'm fairly new. Now I'm trying to figure out how to give full access to the admin according to my setup. But kind of stuck on how to get this implemented.

Comment: I would appreciate a few pointers on which is the best way to setup the users and admin as well. Would it really be best to setup the users all over again? and how should I go about doing this?

Comment: It's pretty hard to answer your questions. Because everything has it pros and cons. And I can't you give big design advises, because I would need to go very deep to the project. I think going with one table is much simpler in case of accesses, etc